# gThumb not showing thumbnails after software update

Tags: 12.04, gthumb

I just did a software update in 12.04 and it seems that gThumb was included in those updates. Suddenly, huge amounts of thumbnails, in the gThumb browser, are not displaying. They're there because the scrollbar indicates as much, but they're completely invisible.

Some show, here and there.

Any idea what this is related to? Anyone getting the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, and the solution was to use a `ppa` and update to `gthumb 3.01`.
For some reason I couldn't build `gthumb` from source properly (which I would normally do), and so tried the `ppa`. See more information [here](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/gthumb) on the ppa. You could try to build it from source if my solution doesn't work for you: see the instructions [here](https://live.gnome.org/gthumb/development).

(By the way it is confusing as in the repositories`gthumb 2.14`, the default Precise version, is labelled as `3:2.14.3-0ubuntu1`)

Remove gthumb:

```
sudo apt-get purge gthumb
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Add the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gthumb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```

[image]